# Triangles that are sometimes equilateral and sometimes not?

Tags: c++, list, math, vertex

I am trying to produce random equilateral triangles on the console screen.

The method I am using is creating a center point for the triangle (randomly positioned), moving the center point to the origin (0,0) and then creating 3 points from the center (adding the radius(random number) of the triangle to the Y axis of each point). Then I rotate 2 of the points, one at 120 degrees and the other at 240 making an equilateral triangle then draw lines between the points. Then bring the points back to the original plot relating to the centroid.

This for the most past of the time works and I get an equilateral triangle, however other times I don't quite get an equilateral triangle and I am at a complete loss as to why.

I am using Brensenham's line algorithm to draw the line between points.

Image of working triangle: http://imgur.com/GpF406O

Image of broken triangle: http://imgur.com/Oa2BYun

Here is the code that plots the coords for the triangle:

```
void Triangle::createVertex(Vertex cent)
{
// angle of 120 in radians
double s120 = sin(2.0943951024);
double c120 = cos(2.0943951024);
// angle of 240 in radians
double s240 = sin(4.1887902048);
double c240 = cos(4.1887902048);

// bringing centroid to the origin and saving old pos to move later on
int x = cent.getX();
int y = cent.getY();
cent.setX(0);
cent.setY(0);

// creating the points all equal distance from the centroid
Vertex v1(cent.getX(), cent.getY() + radius);
Vertex v2(cent.getX(), cent.getY() + radius);
Vertex v3(cent.getX(), cent.getY() + radius);

// rotate points
double newx = v1.getX() * c120 - v1.getY() * s120;
double newy = v1.getY() * c120 + v1.getX() * s120;

double xnew = v2.getX() * c240 - v2.getY() * s240;
double ynew = v2.getY() * c240 + v2.getX() * s240;

// giving the points the actual location in relation the the old pos of the centroid
v1.setX(newx + x);
v1.setY(newy + y);

v2.setX(xnew + x);
v2.setY(ynew + y);

v3.setX(x);
v3.setY(y + radius);

// adding the to a list (list is used in a function to draw the lines)
vertices.push_back(v1);
vertices.push_back(v2);
vertices.push_back(v3);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the images of your two triangles it looks like you might be drawing the triangles with pixels (represented by text characters), which makes for discreet allowable locations to draw each vertex (either this row of pixels or the next one.) My guess is that your algorithm for drawing the lines has to make some sort of call (draw this pixel in row a or row b) and the same row is not getting chosen for both vertices.. Without more detail on the implementation you are using for the line drawing algorithm it would be hard to say one way or the other though.

Comment: The discrepancy in choice of row to print the vertex in could arise if the height value that should be calculated is on (or very very near) the height for the boundary between the two rows and floating point error makes one just above and the other just below.  Most often in software when that happens a floor is called so the one just below ends up in the  next row down.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the images of your two triangles (and looking at the line drawing algorithm) you are drawing lines as a series of discrete pixels. That means a vertex must fall in a pixel (it can't be on a boundary) like in this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#/media/File:Bresenham.svg).

So what happens if your vertex falls on* a border between pixels? Your line drawing algorithm has to make a decision on which pixel to put the vertex in.

Looking at the algorithm description on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and the c++ implementation on a page a [www.cs.helsinki.fi](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html)
I see that both list implementations using integer arithmetic** which in this case is not unreasonable given you have discreet rows of pixels. This means that if your floating point calculations put one vertex above the threshold of the integer label for the next row of pixels when the floor (conversion from float to int) is done, but the other vertex is below that threshold then the two vertices will be placed on different rows.

think `v1.y = 5.00000000000000000001` and `v2.y =  4.99999999999999999999` which leads to v1 being placed on row 5 and v2 being placed on row 4.

This explains why you only see the issue occurring occasionally, you only occasionally have your vertices land on a boundary like this.

In order to fix a couple of things come to mind:

Fix it when you assign values to your vertices, the y values are the same anyways.

given:

```
v1.getX() = v2.getX() = 0 (defined by your code)
v1.getY() = v2.getY() = radius (defined by your code)
cos(120 degrees) = cos(240 degrees) ('tis true)
```

This reduces your two y values to

```
double newy = v1.getY() * c120
double ynew = v1.getY() * c120
```

ergo:

```
v1.setY(newy + y);
v2.setY(newy + y);
```

If you wrote your own Brensenham's algorithm implementation you could add a check in that code to make sure your vertices are at the same height, but that seems like a really bad place to put that kind of check since the height of the endpoints is specific to your problem and not drawing lines in general.

---

*Or not exactly on, but close enough you can't tell the difference after accounting for floating point error

**The algorithm is not restricted to integer arithmetic, but I suspect given the irregularity of your problem and the way the algorithm has been presented, along with the fact that you are using discreet characters for the lines in your images the integer arithmetic is the issue.